# Are there any common system fonts that maintain decent legibility at small sizes?

Tags: font-recommendation, font-size

Are any of the common Windows fonts more legible than others at small sizes, such as 6pt?

I know that there are some free fonts (such as PT Sans) that have decent caption styles, but I'm looking specifically for common system fonts.

**Edit:**

Related question: [Are there ways to make a font more legible at smaller sizes?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71349/are-there-ways-to-make-a-font-more-legible-at-smaller-sizes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Verdana* is a typeface that has sacrificed a lot (a **lot** in my humble opinion) of style to just be legible.

- The lowercase letters are high when compared to the capitals ('it has
  a large x-height' in typographer's terms);
- The counters are large;
- It's a sans serif;
- There are virtually no details that have been rendered subtle or small.

[image]